# No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’

Tags: haskell, show

No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show a’

```
data LTree a = Leaf a | Node (LTree a) (LTree a)
instance Show (LTree a) where
    show (Leaf a) = "{" ++ show a ++ "}"
    show (Node fe fd) = "<" ++ (show fe)++ "," ++(show fd)++ ">"
```

```
Node (Leaf 1) (Node (Node (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4)) (Node (Leaf 8) (Leaf 7)))
```

I should get:

```
<{1},<<{3},{4}>,<{8},{7}>>>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your line:

> ```
>     show (Leaf a) = "{" ++ show a ++ "}"
> ```

You call `show a`, with `a` an element of type `a`, but it is *not* said that that type `a` is an instance of `Show`, you thus need to add a constraint to your `instance` declaration:

```
instance Show a => Show (LTree a) where
    show (Leaf a) = "{" ++ show a ++ "}"
    show (Node fe fd) = "<" ++ (show fe)++ "," ++(show fd)++ ">"
```

So here we say that `LTree a` is an instance of show *given* `a` is an instance of `Show`. For your given sample data, we then obtain:

```
Prelude> Node (Leaf 1) (Node (Node (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4)) (Node (Leaf 8) (Leaf 7)))
<{1},<<{3},{4}>,<{8},{7}>>>
```

Comment: ...and the error even tells you that this is the solution. "Possible fix: add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration".